# Pyinstaller with Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pyinstaller

I have created the REST API using Django REST Framework and it is as expected behaviour. Now i want to make as distribute using pyinstaller. I'm getting error as below,

> django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template
>   library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load
>   'django.template.defaulttags': No module named defaulttags [5556]
>   Failed to execute script manage

Can anyone suggest me, how to fix this error.

Comment: have you configure this?